# Mass insertions in Feynman diagrams

Tags: supersymmetry, feynman-diagrams

I'm trying to calculate some Feynman diagrams for $Z\rightarrow q\bar{q}$ at one-loop order in RPV SUSY with some $B$-violating vertices; these are triangle diagrams with 1-2 squark lines running in the loop. However, the RPV SUSY vertex violates $B$ involves right-handed (s)quarks while the weak interactions affect only left-handed quarks, so I need a chirality flip / mass insertion to obtain a valid interaction.

What specific factor does the mass insertion correspond to in translating from my Feynman diagram to an expression for the amplitude?